# How to modify the post interface of the telescope js

Tags: javascript, meteor, telescope

I am recently learn the source code of the telescope, which build on Meteor. I want to modify the interface of the post page. But when I open the file of 
`/packages/telescope-posts/lib/client/templates/post_body.html`, I can't find the definition of `{{{htmlbody}}}`. Who can tell me where to find this variables. I just want to modify the interface of the post, and I can't find which file or template realized that.

The `post_body.html` is follow:

```
<template name="post_body">
  <div class="post-body markdown" aria-live="polite">{{{htmlBody}}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: It seems that `htmlBody` is a field of the respective document. Triple brackets are used to render data as HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. Do you know which file realized the interface of post?

Comment: What do you mean by "interface of post"?

Comment: Telescope has a function of Post. I want to change the web page(interface) of the post. In other word, I want to design the page by myself. So which template or file realize the page in source code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you please elaborate? It sounds to me like you are trying to modify the way `htmlBody` is set up. The `{{{htmlBody}}}` expression just outputs the user input from the `/packages/telescope-posts/lib/client/templates/post_submit.html`. Do you want to modify the data structure of documents in the `Posts` collection?

Comment: oh, no. May be I have misunderstand the pakage of posts. I just want to modify the web page which we use in telescope. I don't know which part realized this page. I want to find it, it's may not be the {{{htmlBody}}}.
   the page is follow:

Comment: http://demo2.telescopeapp.org/submit

Comment: This is the corresponding template: `/packages/telescope-posts/lib/client/templates/post_submit.html`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It seem that this page realized by the template of "bootstap3-horizontal". So can I modified it ? You are very kind. I will try it by myself.

Comment: The `post_submit.html` template currently includes a form provided by the [meteor-autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) package.

Comment: Oh, that's all right, I finally konw "quickForm" which come from meteor-autoform. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding template you are searching is named `post_submit.html` which is located in `/packages/telescope-posts/lib/client/templates/` ([access file on GitHub](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/packages/telescope-posts/lib/client/templates/post_submit.html)).

This template currently includes the [meteor-autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) package:

```
<template name="post_submit">
  <div class="grid grid-module">
    {{> quickForm collection="Posts" id="submitPostForm" template="bootstrap3-horizontal" input-col-class="controls" type="method" meteormethod="submitPost" fields=postFields}}
  </div>
</template>
```

This package provides an [extendable template system](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#theme-templates) with various built-in templates like `bootstrap3`. If you want to use your own classes to customise the layout, use the `plain` template, which will generate UI elements without a framework.